# Background image cleaning for OCR

Tags: python, image, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

Through tesseract-OCR I am trying to extract text from the following images with a red background.

[image]

I have problems extracting the text in boxes B and D because there are vertical lines. How can I clean the background like this:

input:

[image]

output:

[image]

some idea?
The image without boxes:
[image]

Comment: could you add the input image without the marked boxes so we can experiment with various techniques

Answer (score 6):

Here are two methods to clean the image using Python OpenCV

**Method #1: Numpy thresholding**

Since the vertical lines, horizontal lines, and the background are in red we can take advantage of this and use Numpy thresholding to change all red pixels above a threshold to white.

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

image[np.where((image > [0,0,105]).all(axis=2))] = [255,255,255]

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Method #2: Traditional image processing**

For a more general approach if the lines were not red we can use simple image processing techniques to clean the image. To remove the vertical and horizontal lines we can construct special kernels to isolate the lines and remove them using masking and bitwise operations. Once the lines are removed, we can use thresholding, morphological operations, and contour filtering to remove the red background. Here's a visualization of the process

---

First we construct vertical and horizontal kernels then `cv2.morphologyEx()` to detect the lines. From here we have individual masks of the horizontal and vertical lines then bitwise-or the two masks to obtain a mask with all lines to remove. Next we bitwise-or with the original image to remove all lines

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now that the lines are removed, we can work on removing the red background. We threshold to obtain a binary image and perform morphological operations to smooth the text

[image]

There are still little dots so to remove them, we find contours and filter using a minimum threshold area to remove the small noise

[image]

Finally we invert the image to get our result

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

# Remove vertical and horizontal lines
kernel_vertical = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
temp1 = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_vertical)
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
temp2 = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, horizontal_kernel)
temp3 = cv2.add(temp1, temp2)
removed = cv2.add(temp3, image)

# Threshold and perform morphological operations
gray = cv2.cvtColor(removed, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,2))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)

# Filter using contour area and remove small noise
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 10:
        cv2.drawContours(close, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

final = 255 - close 
cv2.imshow('removed', removed)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('final', final)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: `@nathancy`. I see you used my image processing method to remove horizontal and vertical lines in your second example. But I really like your first method using numpy. I am still learning all the ins and outs of numpy. Really powerful.

Comment: `@nathancy` I have taken your script for the first method and run it with the image provided and it works fine. But when I replace that image with a 100x100 solid red image (`image = np.full((100,100,3), (0,0,255), dtype=np.uint8)`), there is no change. There result is still solid red. Any idea what is happening? Does that image work for you?

Comment: @fmw42 my guess is that the `np.where()` condition is False. Currently it's `image > [0,0,105]` so only pixels which fulfill all three channels will be counted as true. Since the test red image is `(0,0,255)` only the last channel is True. So changing it to `image >= [0,0,105]` should work

Comment: `@nathancy`. Yes. That was it. Makes sense in hind-sight. Still learning numpy and .all was not quite clear until you confirmed it tested all 3 channels, not just the red. Thanks for clearing that up. Much appreciated. Now measuring the red in the original image, I see it is not pure red at (0,0,255). So that now makes sense, also, as to why it worked there with your original command.